# How to you put your Project BACK under version control when xamarin studio removes it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just upgraded to Lion, and then Mountain Lion,  (11.75 GB of system updates according to Time Machine.) and now Xamarin Studio now says my project is no longer under version control.  I don't want to "publish" it and trash SVN (I DO want to check it in!!), Nor would check-out be a good idea...

As it is under SVN, so I dare not go mucking around with the working directory by copying it to another directory, checking it out and copying it back because there is zillions of .svn folders and that will screw up SVN's house of cards...

So, How do I tell Xamarin "It really is under SVN, Please remember what you had before the update?

Thanks.

PS: I was hoping that this would result in an upgrade to 1.7 of SVN, but that doesn't seem to be the case.. (And last time I tried installing 1.7 I had to roll the whole machine back as it ended up hopelessly messing up everything)

Comment: I just checked the Publish option... SVN is no longer supported?  Sigh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Studio's SVN support requires SVN to be installed. Recent version of Xcode (since 4.3) no longer do this automatically. You will have to install the "Xcode command line tools" in Xcode Preferences->Downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer from mhutch that the Xcode does not include the SVN any more, just I had to install the SVN with the help of the command:

xcode-select --install

in the terminal, because the way it was suggested by mhutch did not work for me.